# Conditional in the Past

Tags: conditional-constructions

We say:

**If he comes, I will help him**

What if we add **"She knew"**?

**She knew that if he came I would help him**

Is it correct?

What if we say:

**If he has arrived by April, I would help him**

And then **"she knew"** goes

**She knew that if he had arrived by April, I would help him**

Correct?

Comment: *If he has arrived by April, I **will** help him.* (April hasn't arrived yet, so the second verb must be in the future tense.) Also, *If she **knows** that he **has** arrived by April, I **will** help him.*

Comment: Oh, yeah, about "will", yeah, it was a typo.
But in the second we add not "She knows" but "She knew".

Comment: Okay. *She knew that if he arrived by April, I would help him.* (It's the *he **had** arrived* that was throwing me off.)

Comment: But why do we say "Past SImple" here instead of Past Perfect if we say Present Perfect in "If he has arrived by April, I will help him" instead of Present Simple?

Comment: I don't follow. What we use is what's idiomatic. There isn't necessarily a *why* about it. It's often just what we settled on. I can tell you what people say and what sounds right. I can't necessarily explain the reasoning behind it. But in this specific case, *if he **had** arrived* only works if the arrival took place in the past. The sentence *itself* is fine—but not if you're still talking about the *future* event that you did in the sentence that came before it. Context is crucial. The same sentence will work in one context, but not another.

Comment: If you want to say that *by April* is a future event in the first sentence, but a past event in the second sentence, then that's fine. There's no problem. I assumed, however, that both sentences were supposed to describe the same event, but with *she knew* added to the second.

Comment: I meant:

**She knew** - was in the past.

**If he had arrived** - was later than **she knew**. It's future in the past

**I would help him** - was later than **if he had arrived**.

Comment: As I said, grammar doesn't exist in isolation from context. The identical sentence can make sense in one context, but not make any sense in another. If the *context* for those two sentences is different, then both sentences are fine. But if they are *both* describing the same event—then one or the other needs to have its verb tenses changed. Simply put: When does *by April* take place in relation to the time of the person saying the sentences? In the past or in the future?

Comment: It's like **I said I would do**. It's unknown whehter it has been done by now but for sure it is in the future for **I said**. Here the same - **by April** is later than **she knew** but it's unknown whether now it's already Aril or not yet. I can give context but I have made it too big to post here. I can send it directly to you if it's possible to create the personal chat.